# Custom number format: comma preceding last two digits

Tags: excel, excel-2007

How do I format numbers in cells as follows:

- 12 as 12
- 123 as 1,23
- 1234 as 12,34
- 12345 as 123,45

I tried `##,##`, but this formats 42343 as 42,343 instead of the desired 423,43

`####,##` also not working.

Comment: What do the numbers "mean"? Except the first example they look like "percent". Is this value encoding necessary? (also check http://jonvonderheyden.net/excel/a-comprehensive-guide-to-number-formats-in-excel/)

Comment: @xmojmr: There are different numbering formats out there. The [Indian numbering system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Numbering_System) is but one example ([Excel number format implementation](http://www.yogeshguptaonline.com/2009/10/excel-number-format-indian-style-comma.html)).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I know there are different numbering formats and the India was actually the inventor (as explained in the document [The Story of 1 One - Documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSpadYjnYl8)). My question is about why in THIS case it is necessary to format the numbers differently. What do the numbers MEAN to the end-user. Sometimes simplifying the data representation into 2 or more calculated columns (as suggested by userNaN) may lead to simpler solution of the problem. That is where I'm heading to

Comment: Although @Jean-FrançoisCorbett already solve it for you (at least in my opinion), [check this out](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-custom-number-format-HP010342372.aspx) to see how his formula works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This custom format code works for the examples in your question:

```
[>=100]#\,#0;#
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `=IF(LEN(A1)<3,A1,REPLACE(A1,LEN(A1)-1,0,","))`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is working fine, but my expectation is for expression for the number formatting. As a function this is perfect, appreciate your concern on this regards.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Format>Cells>Custom and type in :

0","00